# Background Fetch, UILocalNotification and Apple Watch

Tags: ios, iphone, notifications, uilocalnotification, apple-watch

I write an iPhone app with Apple Watch. My app should implement the background fetch mode and if there is new data, I send a UILocalNotification and I want my Apple Watch be able to display this notification.

The background fetch part and also the notification works both very well, but the notification is never display in my Apple Watch, even if my iPhone is in sleep mode.

But if I try the same thing but without background fetch, just scheduling a UILocalNotification each minute, all is ok and I can see my notification in my Apple Watch.

So I suppose there is an issue when the notification is sent from the "performFetchWithCompletionHandler" method, however I don't understand why and what I can do to correct this behaviour.

This is my code in my app delegate:

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire


@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?


    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

        let settings = UIUserNotificationSettings.init(forTypes: UIUserNotificationType.Alert, categories: nil)

        UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)

        UIApplication.sharedApplication().setMinimumBackgroundFetchInterval(UIApplicationBackgroundFetchIntervalMinimum)

        return true
    }

    func application(application: UIApplication, didRegisterUserNotificationSettings notificationSettings: UIUserNotificationSettings) {
        print("App is registered to receive local notifications")
    }

    func application(application: UIApplication, performFetchWithCompletionHandler completionHandler: (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {

        print("########### Received Background Fetch ###########");

        if isConnectedToNetwork() {
            // Download  the Content
            let urlString = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().stringForKey(kServerUrl)

            Alamofire.request(.GET, urlString!, parameters: nil)
                .responseJSON() { response in
                    print(response.request)  // original URL request
                    print(response.response) // URL response
                    print(response.data)     // server data
                    print(response.result)   // result of response serialization

                    if let JSON = response.result.value {
                        print("JSON: \(JSON)")
                        self.sendLocalNotification(JSON as! [String : String])
                        completionHandler(.NewData);
                    } else {
                        completionHandler(.NoData)
                    }
            }
        } else {
            print("No Internet connection: unable to fetch data.")
            completionHandler(.NoData)
        }
    }

    private func sendLocalNotification(dictionary: [String: String]) {

        let seatInfo = dictionary["seat"]
        let seat = "Seat: \(seatInfo)"

        let amountInfo = dictionary["amount"]
        let amount = "Amount: \(amountInfo)"

        let localNotification = UILocalNotification()

        localNotification.fireDate = NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow: 0)
        localNotification.alertTitle = "New order"
        localNotification.alertBody = seat + "\n" + amount

        UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(localNotification)
    }  
}
```

And here in my NotificationController.swift:

```
import WatchKit
import Foundation

class NotificationController: WKUserNotificationInterfaceController {

@IBOutlet var alertLabel : WKInterfaceLabel!
@IBOutlet var bodyLabel : WKInterfaceLabel!

override init() {
    // Initialize variables here.
    super.init()

    // Configure interface objects here.
}

override func willActivate() {
    // This method is called when watch view controller is about to be visible to user
    super.willActivate()
}

override func didDeactivate() {
    // This method is called when watch view controller is no longer visible
    super.didDeactivate()
}

override func didReceiveLocalNotification(localNotification: UILocalNotification, withCompletion completionHandler: ((WKUserNotificationInterfaceType) -> Void)) {
    self.alertLabel.setText(localNotification.alertTitle)
    self.bodyLabel.setText(localNotification.alertBody)
    completionHandler(.Custom)
}
}
```